# How can i scale warranty server when IP is fixed

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a problem when work with Bank. 
They need IP and url for API is fixed.

But sometime server die with unknow error. I try to using load balance, but load balance IP is change over time.

Comment: Are you accessing them, or are they accessing you?

Answer (score 0):

Run an EC2 with an Elastic IP assigned to it.  This is your fixed IP

Install some proxying software on the EC2 such as Varnish, Apache with mod_proxy or ha_proxy.  Configure it to forward the incoming requests to the domain name associated with the ELB

Comment: Good idea! But sometime proxy server can be die

Comment: Put the EC2 proxy server in a scaling group of one and health check it with cloudwatch then if there is a problem the server will restart.   Anything *can* go wrong, trick is to deal with it